# Angular-fullstack Heroku Deployment giving error

Tags: angularjs, heroku, angular-fullstack

I'm new to heroku app deployment.. I did it all the steps describe in deployment process also defined all config var.. but still I'm not able to run the application .. this is the log I got from heroku.. please if anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong or missing here

also it is giving `MongoError: Authentication failed` though I have declare config vars in heroku for mongodb connection as `MONGOLAB_URI` key..

```
    2016-12-25T11:51:14.676128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=demo-fullstack.herokuapp.com request_id=673145a1-c8ce-4f2c-a717-b3bfe05c5b
01 fwd="116.73.192.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-12-25T11:51:15.091210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=demo-fullstack.herokuapp.com request_id=05f9ef8a-1d51-4f0e-addb
-1a32ca0afff2 fwd="116.73.192.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-12-25T11:58:07.431140+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-25T11:58:09.585660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-12-25T11:58:11.842396+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T11:58:11.842417+00:00 app[web.1]: > testfullstack@0.0.0 start /app
2016-12-25T11:58:11.842419+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T11:58:11.842418+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/app.js
2016-12-25T11:58:12.800506+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on 10075, in production mode
2016-12-25T11:58:12.853885+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB connection error: MongoError: Authentication failed.
2016-12-25T11:58:12.870567+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T11:58:12.877910+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2016-12-25T11:58:12.877951+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-12-25T11:58:12.878095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2016-12-25T11:58:12.878212+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2016-12-25T11:58:12.878334+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-12-25T11:58:12.878429+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! testfullstack@0.0.0 start: `node server/app.js`
2016-12-25T11:58:12.878531+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 255
2016-12-25T11:58:12.878647+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-12-25T11:58:12.878731+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the testfullstack@0.0.0 start script 'node server/app.js'.
2016-12-25T11:58:12.878807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-12-25T11:58:12.878873+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the testfullstack package,
2016-12-25T11:58:12.878943+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-12-25T11:58:12.879039+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-12-25T11:58:12.879108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server/app.js
2016-12-25T11:58:12.879191+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-12-25T11:58:12.879382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs testfullstack
2016-12-25T11:58:12.879463+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-12-25T11:58:12.879534+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls testfullstack
2016-12-25T11:58:12.879649+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-12-25T11:58:12.883330+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T11:58:12.883479+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-12-25T11:58:12.883553+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-12-25T11:58:12.961081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-25T11:58:12.962211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-25T11:58:12.952734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-12-25T11:58:14.598687+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-12-25T11:58:15.646836+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T11:58:15.646847+00:00 app[web.1]: > testfullstack@0.0.0 start /app
2016-12-25T11:58:15.646847+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/app.js
2016-12-25T11:58:15.646848+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T11:58:16.389173+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on 38372, in production mode
2016-12-25T11:58:16.436177+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB connection error: MongoError: Authentication failed.
2016-12-25T11:58:16.445122+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T11:58:16.452364+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2016-12-25T11:58:16.452548+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-12-25T11:58:16.452685+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2016-12-25T11:58:16.452807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2016-12-25T11:58:16.452925+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453022+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! testfullstack@0.0.0 start: `node server/app.js`
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453103+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 255
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453195+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453276+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the testfullstack@0.0.0 start script 'node server/app.js'.
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453355+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the testfullstack package,
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453512+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453601+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453679+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server/app.js
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453762+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-12-25T11:58:16.453840+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs testfullstack
2016-12-25T11:58:16.454017+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-12-25T11:58:16.454098+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls testfullstack
2016-12-25T11:58:16.454176+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-12-25T11:58:16.457449+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T11:58:16.457596+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-12-25T11:58:16.457665+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-12-25T11:58:16.520594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-25T11:58:16.492087+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-12-25T12:20:14.300271+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-25T12:20:16.246959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-12-25T12:20:18.706498+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T12:20:18.706509+00:00 app[web.1]: > testfullstack@0.0.0 start /app
2016-12-25T12:20:18.706510+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/app.js
2016-12-25T12:20:18.706511+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T12:20:19.622220+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on 28155, in production mode
2016-12-25T12:20:19.710471+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB connection error: MongoError: Authentication failed.
2016-12-25T12:20:19.726340+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T12:20:19.738178+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2016-12-25T12:20:19.738427+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-12-25T12:20:19.738641+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2016-12-25T12:20:19.738825+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2016-12-25T12:20:19.739011+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-12-25T12:20:19.739166+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! testfullstack@0.0.0 start: `node server/app.js`
2016-12-25T12:20:19.739573+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the testfullstack@0.0.0 start script 'node server/app.js'.
2016-12-25T12:20:19.739294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 255
2016-12-25T12:20:19.739443+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-12-25T12:20:19.739697+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-12-25T12:20:19.739824+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the testfullstack package,
2016-12-25T12:20:19.740093+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-12-25T12:20:19.739951+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-12-25T12:20:19.740222+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server/app.js
2016-12-25T12:20:19.740362+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-12-25T12:20:19.740452+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs testfullstack
2016-12-25T12:20:19.740570+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-12-25T12:20:19.740700+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls testfullstack
2016-12-25T12:20:19.741006+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-12-25T12:20:19.746333+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-25T12:20:19.746571+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-12-25T12:20:19.746693+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-12-25T12:20:19.818450+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-12-25T12:20:19.827787+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Is your favicon.ico existent?

Comment: yes it does..  /public/favicon.ico

Comment: It is being searched at /favicon.ico so I suppose you are searching it in the wrong location.

Comment: I thought the same.. But it is working fine locally.. or even if I serve dist.. just on heroku deployment it is giving error.. I didn't make any changes to dir structure..

Comment: Akshay it seems your favicon exists locally but not in your deploy environment. Can you check whether it is existent at the deployment environment?

Comment: Yes it surely exists.. cause I've given link of my github repo in heroku.. and I've checked in repo as well that it exists..

Comment: @LajosArpad just to let you know that deployment did work.. actually there was no fault of favicon.ico as we thought from the log.. but I had given the wrong user name and/or password for mongodb connection.. Thanks for the help..